# Open Graph Meta Tags in Body?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I am trying to add open graph meta tags to our video pages on our website, but for some reason they are not being picked up by Facebook. I believe I'm doing everything as is posted on the developer pages.

Here is an example link:
http://www.atlantafalcons.com/falconstv/?video_id=1750246128001

The linter returns the following error:

> Meta Tags In Body:    You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable.
>   http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.atlantafalcons.com%2Ffalconstv%2F%3Fvideo_id%3D1750246128001

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration has a closing slash `/>` on it when it is not supposed to. This, and other misplaced characters, can cause erroneous behavior on different levels and tools. The 'Meta Tags in Body' message is more than likely caused by that.